# Splunk issue with Telegram Alert Action: Can not configure the action

Tags: telegram-bot, splunk

I installed Telegram Alert Action app (https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3703/) for my SearchHead server (Splunk Enterprise 8.0.6) successfully. But when i add Telegram Alert action for the alerts, i can not see any its configurations as attached image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wWWR.png

Could any one tell me what is this issue?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have solved the issue this way:

1. Add the Telegram alert action for the alerts in Web UI, and Save the changes.
2. Open SSH session to SearchHead server, find and open the file that contains configurations of the alerts that were added Telegram alert action, and add more 5 lines below the line `action.telegram = 1` and save the changes:

```
action.telegram.param.bot_id = Bot-ID
action.telegram.param.chat_id = Chat-ID
action.telegram.param.severity = Low/Medium/High/Critical
action.telegram.param.event_title = Alert title
action.telegram.param.message = Alert message
```

3. Finally, reload/restart Splunk in the SH server, and enjoy the
   results!

Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: so you *did* update the configuration, as the docs indicated?

Answer (score 0):

What configuration of the add-on have you done?

According to https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3703/#/details, you need to have Chat & Bot IDs (ref: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

Do you have them?

Comment: Hi Warren,
When i add Telegram alert action for the alerts, it does not show any configurations, it shows only "This alert action does not require any user configuration".

Comment: I changed owner of folder "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/alert_telegram" from "root:root" to "splunk:splunk" too, but it does not make any effects.

Comment: @TonyNgo - according to the app's docs (which I linked), there *is* a configuration which must be set (the Chat and Bot IDs). Do you have those created and available?

Comment: Yes, I had created Bot ID and Chat ID already. But as i said with attached image: when i add Telegram alert action for the alerts, it does not show the boxes to input the Bot ID and Chat ID

Comment: @TonyNgo - so you *did* update the configuration, as the docs indicated?